# Performance issues of Sencha 4 multipage mobile application

Tags: javascript, cordova, extjs, mobile

I have a Sencha application, that consists of multiple Sencha applications, that are served through ASP.NET files. I'm facing lot of performance issues with mobile browsers. The application is converted to a hybrid application by cordova. I thought it could be about cordova using default webviews, but I also tried the app with regular Chrome (on Android), and the performance is as bad.

Loading a new Sencha app for some reason takes a lot of time for the mobile browsers, and I don't know exactly why. And because the app consist of multiple Sencha applications, it is performing slow. Do you know if there is anything that could be done to improve the performance? I don't know Sencha very well (yet;)). I think I could try Crosswalk for addition with cordova, but since it is not running well in Chrome, I'm not sure if it will help.

When the Sencha app is run on a PC browser, it runs fast. Like 5 times faster at least.

Comment: are you loading your asp server pages in mobile app ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It seems that evaluating and running the sencha framework takes lot of time in mobile browsers. I was wondering if I could cache the sencha framework? But that would just cache it, which means it would still have to be loaded when a new sencha app is started

Comment: How your server pages are served using ajax or normal server mechanism where server creates HTML document for you and client will render it. By Ajax client will load HTML first and then manipulate it with ajax requests.   If ajax is your workaround then you might take your HTML source code to develop a Phonegap app. As code resides with in app it may increases your app performance too.. As there is no need to req. HTML pages on server.

Comment: Above workflow only works if you only using ajax mechanism

Comment: Normal server mechanism, just url. I know the application would perform better if the code resided in the app itself (through cordova wrap for example). But in this case what is wanted is that the application updates simply by updating server code. So once a person has the application, he always has the newest version. How the hybrid app works now is that there is a native login side, and after that, all comes from server.

Comment: Ohk I understand ur problem. But I don't have any suggestions for that.